# How to capture the table from website into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, string-formatting

I want to capture the data from table given in the website and store it into the Pandas dataframe with predefined columns. I tried with capturing the same, but I am not able to segregate the data columnwise.
Below is my attempt on this;

```
import pandas as pd
import lxml.html as lh    
site= 'https://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/guide/phone-under-10000-best-mobile-india-price-realme-redmi-samsung-vivo-camera-battery-2240177'
    docc= lh.fromstring((requests.get(site)).content)
    tr_= docc.xpath('//tr')
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Phones', 'rating (out of 10)', 'Price in India'])
    for t in range(0,len(tr_)):
        row= tr_[t]
        for (value) in row.iterdescendants():
            phone= (value.text)
            #print(phone)
            dataset = df.append({'Phones':str(phone)},ignore_index=True)
```

But here I am not able to capture the data for **'Phones'**, **'rating (out of 10)'** and **'Price in India'**

Comment: For this specific case, it's easier to just copy the table and paste it into excel. It preserves the format and then you can save it and import with pandas.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    df = pd.read_html(r.content)[0]
    print(df)
    df.to_csv("data.csv")


main("https://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/guide/phone-under-10000-best-mobile-india-price-realme-redmi-samsung-vivo-camera-battery-2240177")
```

Output:

```
  Phones under Rs. 10,000  Gadgets 360 rating (out of 10) Price in India (as recommended)
0               Realme C3                               8                       Rs. 7,999    
1        Realme Narzo 10A                               8                       Rs. 8,499    
2                 Redmi 8                               7                       Rs. 9,499    
3                Realme 5                               8                       Rs. 9,999    
4                Vivo U10                               7                       Rs. 9,990    
5               Realme U1                               8                       Rs. 8,499    
6      Samsung Galaxy M30                               8                      Rs. 10,035
```

Comment: Seems a simple solution for the query..
But I need to share the same result in a dataframe created in my code. 
( df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Phones', 'rating (out of 10)', 'Price in India'])